Little water worlds
In a solar system, not too dissimilar to our own, there are dozens of little ice moons and water spheres (similar to moons) near the sun. Some slingshot close to the sun (where they boil and kill all the inhabitants), there are some in stable orbits around planets and gas giants. And some in long orbits out to the Oort Cloud and back. Some freeze solid and return aeons later with ancient civilizations in the ice.
How could these droplets continue existing long term, without all of them getting captured by planets in the long run - or merging to the watery equivalent of Jupiters? How could a stable society exist, flourish and migrate from droplet to droplet?

Superstitions are opinion based, as much as this question

A pure water world that wasn't already frozen would lose its volatiles (eg. liquid water) to the vacuum very quickly.  Water spheres in space without a metallic core to provide a magnetosphere would vanish doubly quick.

Dropped it down to one question. The superstition question removed entirely.

Comets are what exists in our current solar system that best bit fit the description in terms of orbit.

Would you be willing to put them in clear balloons made of Sufficiently Advanced Materials Technology? Maybe some incredibly advanced ancient civilization had a space ship accident a million years ago and lost their cargo / fuel pods, and humans found them later, orbiting a star.

@g it would be okay to wrap them in a material that prevents evaporation

The problem is that vacuum does not, as most people - myself included - tend to think, behave like so much cold air; the total lack of pressure does unexpected things.
In this case the surface of the water blobs is presented with no partial pressure of water vapour and will simultaneously boil because there is no pressure keeping it liquid and freeze due to evaporative cooling. The net result is to form an ice crust over any such floating ocean. If exposed to enough stellar radiation this ice crust will sublime into space. You might expect that to create an atmosphere but there are two things against that, firstly a sphere of water has 25% or less of the mass of a sphere of rock of the same diameter so gravity is ~6% or less of that for a rock of comparable size, meaning the gas escape velocity is proportionately very low.
Secondly, without a strong magnetosphere the solar winds strip the water vapour off into space continuously. In short, any such body of water directly exposed to space will disappear on the solar winds in the blink of an eye, geologically speaking. What you need is some protection from vacuum otherwise sorry no.

Could such a ocean be coated by a "oil" or another substance that would prevent the boiling while staying liquid in vaccum.. Or simply have a small atmosphere of water steam around it?

@Pica Um, maybe? Apart from a shrug that's all I've got on that one sorry. The atmosphere runs up against lack of gravity and magnetosphere, the solar winds are going to blow it off as fast as it forms, or faster.

It could reassemble though to water dropletss in gravitational tight spots?

@Pica What are "gravitational tight spots"?  Gravity comes with mass, and as Ash points out, water doesn't have much of that, by volume.  The only planet in the solar system less dense than water is Saturn, and it achieves that by being a long way from the sun.  If you want liquid water, you need a terrestrial planet to hold it in place.  Or a giant pressurized framework around it.

Also, @Pica, water vapour blown away by the solar wind will have no chance of "reassembly".  Space is very, very big, and vacuum prompts everything to spread out a lot unless there's a countervailing force like an enormous gravity well.  The pressure from the solar wind would keep the vapour going until it was so ridiculously diffuse that it would never come back together.

But we have gases, that come back together, to form suns? So why not have copious amounts of gasous water driven back together via external solarwinds at the edge of the system? If this overcomplicated aquarium would have another sun nearby, whose solar winds would drive the water back together?

@Pica Even if we go with either the "gravitational tight spot" or the external solar wind driven reconvergence of the material, and both are a hard no, water in vacuum will not have a liquid surface, period.

@Pica - stellar nurseries have masses of gas and dust that start at about a thousand solar masses and go up from there.  Massive accumulations of matter can trigger the collapse and formation of stellar nuclei that themselves start accumulating more matter.  The stellar core is not hydrogen, but much heavier matter that accumulates the gas, as with our gas giants.  So a) water alone wouldn't work, and b) you'd have to start with a mass of water somewhere around one and a half quadrillion times that of all water on earth to precipitate coalescing from a molecular cloud.

How do you get from 25% to 6%?  The surface gravity of a sphere is proportional to radius × density.
